# Passing GET response to POST

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, post, get

I am trying to pass multiple maps of data dependent on the id selected to an export to Excel method.

I'm trying to use AngularJS to pass a JSON Array from a GET response to POST using this code:

```
$scope.exportExcel = function() {
var id='?';
angular.forEach($scope.selection, function(value, key) {
    id = id + "id=" + value + '&';
});

$http.get(searchUrl + id).success(
    function(response) { 
        $http.post(exportUrl, response);
    }
)}
```

The response of GET will be a JSON Array that looks like so (let's say Jason and Fred were both selected):

```
response = [{'id':'Jason', 'number':1}, {'id':'Fred', 'number':2}]
```

I have developed the Java code such that the input for the POST method should be like the array above.

I want the user to select the id's, press the EXPORT button, and immediately get a download dialog. No other screen changes or loads.

Is this feasible? Will my POST command be able to receive the JSONArray response from GET and successfully export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works. I just needed affirmation after all. I tested it and it works. Thanks for those who answered.

Answer (score 0):

No reason this won't work. Once the `GET` operation finished and called to its `on-success` function your code is in a whole new domain and the `POST` operation will function normally (it doesn't care or know where the data came from).

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick attempt; Try this (if you can't work with this I'll need more info on what the value looks like -- I don't know the library you're using):

```
$scope.exportExcel = function() {
var id;
angular.forEach($scope.selection, function(value, key) {
    id = (id?id+"&":"?")
       + "id["+key+"]=" + encodeURIComponent(value.id)
       + "&number["+key+"]=" + value.number;
});

$http.get(searchUrl + id).success(
    function(response) { 
        $http.post(exportUrl, response);
    }
)}
```